# What is vmotion?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

How vm migration / datastore migration in different from vmotion in virtualization ?
I was searching for vm migration and datastore migration. Understood what is the difference between host & datastore migration but what is vmotion. How it is related to host or datastore migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help: [https://www.techopedia.com/7/31098/technology-trends/virtualization/what-is-the-difference-between-vmotion-vm-migration-and-live-migration#:~:text=The%20difference%20between%20the%20three,between%20physical%20machines%20without%20interaction](https://www.techopedia.com/7/31098/technology-trends/virtualization/what-is-the-difference-between-vmotion-vm-migration-and-live-migration#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20the%20three,between%20physical%20machines%20without%20interaction).

From URL:

> The difference between the three terms above is that vMotion™ is a trademarked name for a company product, while the other two terms are general terms referencing the methods of migrating virtual machines in a network.

> With VM migration, IT engineers move virtual machines between physical machines without interaction.

Comment: so according to you there is no difference between vmotion and host migration? Then how datastore migration is related to vmotion as vm host migration and datastore kigrations are 2 different thing.